# How to redirect stdout back into stdin

Tags: unix

Quite straight forward question. I would like a program to read its output.

This is not a common thing to do, but it makes a whole lot of tests I have a lot easier as the program can test its output and return success or failure.

Note I can't just read the output as i'm testing the compiler and runtime.

Obviously I can use 2 programs but I would prefer each test to be independent.

Comment: More info please, code, language, precise OS version, etc.

Comment: Why not simply use a pipe?

Comment: Linux (Crunch bang ) , makefiles / command line . Yes considering  test < dev/loop > dev/loop.  Though im not sure this will be the same instance of /dev/loop/